# Google Cloud Vision ImageAnnotator Google Application Credential File Not Exist Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-cloud-platform, google-api-php-client, google-cloud-vision

I have try to implement the google cloud vision with API ImageAnnotator using a codeigniter PHP.

I have install the require google cloud vision using a composer to my third party directory in codeigniter.

This is the code looks like in my controller :

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use Google\Auth\ApplicationDefaultCredentials;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;        

class Manage_center extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        include APPPATH . 'third_party/vendor/autoload.php';
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }


    function upload_ocr_image()
    {               
        //img_data contain image => i just shorten the code.
        $img_data = $this->upload->data();                                          

        // Authenticating with a keyfile path.
        putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.base_url().'assets/google_cloud_vision/credentials.json');
        $scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision'];

        // create middleware
        $middleware = ApplicationDefaultCredentials::getMiddleware($scopes);
        $stack = HandlerStack::create();
        $stack->push($middleware);

        $imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();

        # annotate the image                
        $response = $imageAnnotator->textDetection($img_data['full_path']);             
        $texts = $response->getTextAnnotations();

        printf('%d texts found:' . PHP_EOL, count($texts));
        foreach ($texts as $text) {
            print($text->getDescription() . PHP_EOL);

            # get bounds
            $vertices = $text->getBoundingPoly()->getVertices();
            $bounds = [];
            foreach ($vertices as $vertex) {
                $bounds[] = sprintf('(%d,%d)', $vertex->getX(), $vertex->getY());
            }
            print('Bounds: ' . join(', ',$bounds) . PHP_EOL);
        }

        $imageAnnotator->close();



    }
}
```

I got the error :

> Type: DomainException
>
> Message: Unable to read the credential
>   file specified by  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: file
>   http://localhost/theseeds/assets/google_cloud_vision/credentials.json
>   does not exist
>
> Filename:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\theseeds\application\third_party\vendor\google\auth\src\CredentialsLoader.php
>
> Line Number: 74
>
> File:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\theseeds\application\controllers\Manage_center.php            Line: 3188
>             Function: getMiddleware

I dont understand why this error occur :

http://localhost/theseeds/assets/google_cloud_vision/credentials.json does not exist

Because when i opened the link the file is there.

And this error :

> File:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\theseeds\application\controllers\Admin_center.php            Line: 3188
>             Function: getMiddleware

is a line code :

**$middleware = ApplicationDefaultCredentials::getMiddleware($scopes);**

What is the proper way to use the google cloud vision ImageAnnotatorClient in codeigniter PHP ?

Is there a problem with the authentication to google cloud api ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

This is how the right way to use the google cloud ImageAnnotator with service account key.

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use Google\Cloud\Vision\VisionClient;

class Admin_center extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        include APPPATH . 'third_party/vendor/autoload.php';
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

    function upload_ocr_image() {               
        $img_data = $this->upload->data();                                          

        $vision = new VisionClient(['keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('credentials.json'), true)]);

        $imageRes = fopen($img_data['full_path'], 'r');
        $image = $vision->image($imageRes,['Text_Detection']);
        $result = $vision->annotate($image);

        print_r($result);
    }
}
```